# How to stop output after running an OS command in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, antivirus

I am creating a static Anti virus, for linux by comparing all the files and seeing if any of them are unauthorized.

```
Scan = os.system('tree')
```

When I run this it runs the entire output of the tree command, which is way to big because I brokeout to root direct using the os.chdir command. So how do I stop the output of this command to the screen?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `os.path.walk()` instead of `os.system('tree')`?

Comment: what does os.path.walk() do different?

Comment: If nothing else, `os.system()` just gives you the return value of the call, not the output.

Comment: I cant show you exactly without giving away every file in my linux computer, but when I ran the command after the dir breakout it started to output everything, which is not user friendly at all. and filled up the bash screen very quickly

Comment: ^ That's because `os.system('tree')` is running the command `'tree'` so this is expected... `Scan` as @Iluvatar noted is just the return value of this call. You should be using os.path.walk here.

Comment: Can you tell me the syntax to use os.path.walk()?

Comment: Never mind y'all I am now using os.system('tree > Check1.txt')

Comment: because I am using the dir breakout I also used a os.getuid command to avoid the access denied bug because you can't create text docs in root directory without root privelege